# Подстановка переменной в имя массива, который находится в условии оператора if

Tags: javascript

Мне надо пройтись по 4-м массивам par1, par2, par3, par4 и сравнить значения их первых двух членов с 0. Чтобы не писать 4 if, я хочу сделать цикл for, но для этого мне надо подставить переменную d в имя массива, который находится в условии оператора if. Возможно ли это сделать? Если да, то как? 
Я попробовал вставить как в строку, но  ничего не вышло.

```
var j = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
for (var d=1; d<5; d++){
   if (("par"+d+"[0]") === 0 || ("par"+d+"[1]") === 0))
      a = 1;
   else
      a = 0;
}
```

Comment: сделайте ваши 4 массива не отдельными переменными, а элементами еще одного внешнего массива и сможете спокойно обращаться к элементам как par[d-1][0]

Comment: Отдельной процедурой передавать в цикл имя массива. Цикл оформить в виде отдельной функции

Comment: @Mike Ну да, так будет удобнее. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var d = 1; d < 5; d++) {
    if (window["par" + d][0] === 0 || window["par" + d][1] === 0) {
        a = 1;
    } else {
        a = 0;
    }
}
```